# Create generic type template from string

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following piece of generic code.

```
var base_generic_type = typeof(ConsumerService<,>);
```

I'd really like to be able to use a string to create this type for example

```
var base_generic_type = Type.GetType(serviceTypeName, true);
```

But I can't quite figure out the syntax for creating the generic type template from a string.

I would be most grateful if someone could provide some pointers, all the generic type questions on StackOverflow I can find all start out knowing the basic template type.

Comment: Why not see `base_generic_type.AssemblyQualifiedName`

Comment: I'd like the type of service to be created to be configurable, to use that example I would have to use the first line as described, which means it is not configurable. Thanks anyway Mike.

Comment: Sorry Mike, I see what you mean now it returns a value of ConsumerService`2, which I presume is the number of generic arguments on it. I'll give that a try, thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of `Type.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) i got the following snippet:

```
var typeName = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,MyType]";
var resolvedType = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

I guess with this you should be able to dynamically resolve a type at runtime from a string.

Here you got a [working example in a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aagm3B).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var typeName = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
          + "[System.String,System.String]";
        var resolvedType = Type.GetType(typeName); 
        Console.WriteLine(resolvedType.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep I should look at the MSDN documentation more often, I rely on SO way too much. Worked perfectly, thanks a million to both Mike and Isaias-b